# Break the reply-all chain in mistaken mass email

Tags: email

From time-to-time I see emails which are sent to the entire company (1000's of employees) by accident, normally items related to I.T, server updates, etc. Most people will ignore these and get on with their day.

However there tends to be that one person who replies all, "Please remove me from the list". This leads to several people over the next few days saying "Remove me to!" leading to quite a bit of spam.

Eventually someone will respond, "Please do not reply-all, contact X directly". It does not work.

Some others will respond, "Do not replay to this type of email, it just leads to spam". It does not work.

I have never replied myself, consider it pointless, just wait for the chain to die and delete the spam, however it has got me thinking: has anyone ever managed to create a simple reply-all message that is professional, and that shuts the chain down immediately and permanently? If so, what was that?

Comment: Many email services provide options to prevent mass mailings and mass replies.  You might discuss this with the appropriate email administrators and see if a technical solution is possible.

Comment: @gnat not exactly, because this appears to be related to the folk who replay-all to a real email sent to a group, versus something company wide by mistake where no feedback should be expected at all

Comment: Question: Are you looking at a Technical answer or are you looking for a Workplace policy answer? I mean I can give pointers on both - but in terms of the scope of the question - how much more is needed other than 'Do not do this, those who do will receive disciplinary action'

Comment: This happened once at the national health service (NHS) in the UK. They had a mailing list of 155,000 employees. Their email system just broke down. Myself I observed a case where someone had put “all employees” in the “all employees” mailing list. They shut down email after seven rounds of mail going out.

Comment: I would solve this technically. For emails to a lot of recipients: Do NOT put all email addresses in the To or CC field, use BCC for this. Even better, use mailing lists or other forms of distribution. In mailing lists with a lot of recipients, restrict who can post messages. Use a tool which has an easy way to unsubscribe (for example in the footer with a hopefully not miniscule link to unsubscribe). It is extremely tedious to try to establish rules, such as "do not reply to all".

Comment: Try to make it easier to follow the rules than to not follow them or - even better - make it not possible to not follow the rules in the first place. Otherwise this is a sysiphus job which never ends

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What has to happen is that somebody in IT has to remove the chain. It can be done, though there should be procedures in place to make sure that company and industry compliance procedures aren't violated.

No professional reply-all email will always break the storm because some people are only replying hours or days after it started, they will respond to the 3ed reply-all, and won't notice the others telling them not to respond.

I know some companies limit the ability to reply-all, and issue a warning if more than x people are on the email; these don't always work because those can be overcome or ignored.

Comment: Make a good point, if people are working incrementally through their email, they may reply-all before they get to the please-dont-replay-all message. So therefore it has to be unbreakable

Answer (score 5):

> has anyone ever managed to create a simple reply-all message that is professional, and that shuts the chain down immediately and permanently? If so, what was that?

I worked for a company where the company owner replied all ( after several employees had already started the reply all chain ) and pointed out that he had reached out to the IT group to resolve the issue and prevent it from happening and also said that any further replies would result in disciplinary action.

To my knowledge there were two people who went ahead and replied all to his message and both were shortly let go from the company ( this was in an at will location ).

The point being, that it's not so much the specific wording of the message that will shut down the chain rather it is the person that is sending it and their willingness to follow through with their message.

Comment: So in this case, it didn't work basically, regardless of whether they were willing to follow through with the message?

Comment: @mattfreake aside from those employees nobody else replied all.  Don't know if more employees would have replied all had that message not been sent but the chain was basically shut down after the owner's message.

Comment: Ouch, wonder if they read one of the older emails, decided they were going to reply-all, selected the newest, did not read and just reply-all at that point? Either way, I guess further proof that what you say or who you get to say it does not work

Answer (score 3):

The answer to prevent unwanted replies, is for the sender to BCC the recipients (whether a list or distribution list).

That way, even accidental replies are prevented.

Answer (score 2):

I have an Outlook macro for this situation, linked to a toolbar button in the Compose Mail window:

```
ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Actions("Reply to All").Enabled = False
```

I usually respond with something along the lines of "Disabling Reply-All for this thread to prevent unnecessary replies." It only applies to my own mail, not to any others in the thread, but since a lot of people will reply-all to the most recent message in the thread, this works more often than not.